# Bug in Instagram blocking mechanism?

Tags: instagram

I've used Instagram for years, but just a few weeks ago was the very first time I had to block another user, as he suddenly started spamming my profile with rude comments. Now, this could be just me, but I thought it was very normal and logical to assume that by blocking this user, all of his rude, spammy comments which were spread all over my profile (on almost every post) would be deleted. After all, this is one of the main purposes of blocking someone, right?

But just a few days ago, another user asked me about all of those rude comments on my profile, which was surprising to me because I was absolutely sure I had blocked the guy. To my shocking discovery (after creating another account to check out my own profile), I saw that every single comment he posted on my profile was still there, for everyone to see. As it turns out, by the time I had discovered this, this user had also blocked me, since I couldn't find his profile ANYWHERE. When I searched for it in the Explore section, it said "no results" and when I went to my 'Blocked users' section in my App Settings, his profile wasn't in that list either. In other words, I had lost contact to this profile in every possible way, but his comments were still on display on my profile for everyone to see.

My first intention was to unblock this guy, so his comments would reappear underneath my posts, which would allow to just delete all of his comment manually before re-blocking him again. As I've described above, this was no longer possible. I used the newly created profile, along with a few other 'borrowed' accounts, to report the comments so they would be noticed by an Instagram representative who could then delete those comments for me. Even though every single comment was reported a bunch of times by many different profiles, the comments are still there. Since there is absolutely no other way to get in contact with Instagram (I tried the 'Report a bug' function a bunch of time, but I never got a response or reply), I was at a loss.

Ever since I made this discovery, I'm trying to convince myself that this is just a bug in the particular app installed on my device, because I genuinely can not believe that this is actually what's supposed to happen. I don't think I have to explain to anyone that if this is NOT a bug, we can call this a major, major, MAJOR design flaw in Instagram's blocking system (understatement of the century).

Just think about it for a second: apparently, Instagram allows users to just spam other people and post nasty comments all over their profile, and as long as the spammer just blocks you immediately afterwards, there is absolutely nothing you can do about it, since the posted comments will no longer be visible to you, but will be visible to anyone else who visits your profile. How convenient, right?

Has anyone else had any experience with this? If so, could I get some suggestions on what I should do? I already tried using the 'Hide comments' function, which is a short-term solution for now (hopefully), since I don't plan on adding new nasty words to that dictionary every single time someone post an insult on my profile. I'm secretly still hoping that someone will give me some good news by telling me that this just a bug in my app (which I highly doubt), because if it isn't, I find this kind of negligence by the Instagram developers very very disturbing.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. It's pretty typical for "blocking": You are protected from ever seeing his junk again, but nobody else is. It's one of the big complaints about blocking, especially on places like Twitter. If the comments violate Instagram's TOS, you should be able to report them to Instagram.